# About Hole of compact set in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, operator-theory

Given a compact set $K$ of complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. A hole of $K$ is defined as bounded components of its complement.Then decomposing $$\mathbb{C}/K =\Omega_\infty \cup \Omega_1 \cup\Omega_2\cup.....$$

where $\Omega_\infty$ is unbounded component and $\Omega_i$ are holes .Then it say there will be only finite number of holes or none at all.

My doubt is why there would be a unbounded component and why there are only finite number of holes.

And under what condition there will be no hole at all.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Who said there will be finitely many holes?

Comment: @Adayah in book. where it has taken $K$ to be spectrum of $x$ in a Banach Space

Comment: I don't know much about spectra, but it is definitely not true for an arbitrary compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ that there will be finitely many holes. So more assumptions may be necessary.

Comment: in the plane let $K$ be the closed ball centered at the origin with radius $4$, minus make holes removing the open balls $B(\frac1n,\frac1{4n}).$

Comment: @Mirko The radii should be smaller (of the size of about $\frac{1}{3n^2}$), otherwise the balls will overlap. After the change, the counterexample will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_{n}$,  $n>0$, be the circle of center $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ and radus $\frac{1}{n}$. And $$K=\bigcup_{n>0}C_{n}$$ Then $K$ is a compact in the complex plan and \ $\mathbb{C}$\ $K$ has infinite number of holes.

Comment: $K$ is known as the *Hawaiian earring*.